# A loop that will output every other name in the names list

Tags: python-3.x, oop

When I loop through the given list, it produces this output

```
XXXXXXXXXX
0
2
4
6
8
XXXXXXXXXX
```

From this code:

```
names = ['Peter', 'Bruce', 'Steve', 'Tony', 'Natasha', 'Clint', 'Wanda', 'Hope', 'Danny', 'Carol']

class Names:
        def PrintEveryOtherName(self):
                print(10 * 'X')
                for name in range(0, len(names), 2):
                        print(name)
                print(10 * 'X')
                print('\n')
```

I am trying to print the names and not the location of the elements/names. Additionally if you see anything that's wrong that would be great! thx!

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
for name in names[::2]:
    print(name)
```

or

```
for idx in range(0, len(names), 2):
    print(names[idx])
```